# css transition on border left works on hover but not on mouseout

Tags: html, css, hover, transform, mouseout

I have this css to transform a border-left, on hover a sliding effect to the right happens. When the mouse outs the a tag the border-left should transform back to 0px and a sliding effect back to the left should occur, but it isnt happening. What's wrong?

```
a {
  border-left: 0px solid #32acaf;
  transition: border-left 0.7s;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #473828;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
  border-left: 7px solid #32acaf;
  transition: border-left 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/2jp2p/). Works for me in Chrome, mouseout sliding back just fine.

Comment: This works also in firefox.

Comment: I think the problem is in your HTML. please post relevant html code here.

Comment: Working nice : http://jsfiddle.net/L6VVX/

Answer (score 2):

I have used the css code you have given and checked the output in most of the browser
I have added the html and css code and also the jsfiddle like.

HTML

```
<a>hai</a>
```

css

```
a {
  border-left: 0px solid #32acaf;
  transition: border-left 0.7s;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #473828;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
  border-left: 7px solid #32acaf;
  transition: border-left 0.2s;
}
```

The jsfiddle link is

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZeCz/1929/

Comment: @Rascal Capac  Hai if the helps you then accept my answer and vote up my answer.